# anomaly detection in time series

Tags: python, time-series, anomaly-detection

I have the data set below:

[image]

First column is date(weekly frequency), 2th column is name of commercial banks, 3rd one is identification of bonds. A branch (B branches) values are amount of bonds that held by A branches(B branches) of Banks. I wonder if any outlier can be detected the amounts of bonds held by branches.

Which algorithms can be used for this data set in python.

Note:

- not all bonds are included in every bank.
- a bond can be held in a branch of a bank but may not be in the other.
- a bond may come out of the data set because it is amortized.
- a newly issued bond can enter data set.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you interesting identifying anomalies in time? Ie abnormal changes. Or anomalies/outliers in for example banks/branches, those that have an abnormal amount of bonds? Or abnormal "portefolios" of bonds?

Comment: bond portfolio of a bank over time. Let's say B Bank reported Bond1 for both branches in the first week and continued to report it in other weeks.Are the amounts in the branches abnormal to any week?